# Screen flicker with Intel HD graphics driver

Tags: windows, display, intel-graphics, display-driver

I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 running on my Probook (HP Probook 4530s, core i3/2nd gen/4GB/320GB). It was functioning well. However, the screen started flickering in Win 7.

Upon uninstalling the Intel HD graphics driver and using a standard VGA, the flickering stopped.
I have tried updating the graphics drivers many times but the issue still remains.

Comment: Does it have switchable graphics ?

Comment: To put Moab's question in a frame: There are several posts here on SU which have switchable graphics based on an Intel on die GPU and Nvidia add-on, all about this problem. The memory itself was fine in these cases but once used dual channel glitches occurred inb the graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me after installing the Intel HD 3000 driver my screen flicker randomly sometimes and in most cases on my mouse movement  but after uninstalling it and rolling back to Microsoft basic graphic driver the flickering completely goes away. I am providing 2 solutions for this problem i hope it solves your problem.

1. I think that you are installing wrong graphic driver so what you have to do is type your processor detail with its number on Intel graphics site or google it, for example, I have an Intel i3-2375M CPU with 1.50GHz, so I clicked on this processor compatible Intel HD 3000 64 bit driver and installed it, and my problem was solved. If this also does not work then...
2. Lower your refresh rate. If it is 60hz, reduce it to 40hz.

Answer (score 0):

I've been frantically searching for a solution for this exact same problem for a Lenovo laptop with Intel UHD 620 graphics, running Windows 10, and I have found a lot of similar questions around the web. This is not a new problem, and there are a few different ideas on how to fix it.

What finally worked for me was to install Lenovo's "official" graphics driver, and then go into Intel HD Graphics Control Panel and modify the power options.

(A clue was that the flickering stopped as soon as I moved the mouse, and there was no flickering while Intel HD Graphics Control Panel was on screen. No flickering during boot either -- it started a few seconds after arriving at the welcome screen.)

So, open the power options, which looks like this in the older version:

[image]

Make sure to uncheck *Panel Self-Refresh* for both "Plugged In" and "On Battery". I also switched to *Maximum Performance* when plugged in, but am not sure if that helped.

Hat tip to https://www.digitional.com/how-to-solve-the-screen-flicker-issue-in-pcs-with-intel-graphics/

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was the RAM upgrade that was causing it, i realized that any time i add the new module then the screen starts flickering. so i guessed the new module was either incompatible or defective.

Comment: I don't think it's RAM. I'm unhappy user of ThinkPad T420 which has Intell HD 3000 (GT2+). It often flickers in Win7 x64 but what's worse some apps simply can't render their windows such as Visual Studio 2012 or Resharper. It annoys the hell out of me. No drivers updates helps.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem. After installing the Intel HD Graphics driver the screen started flickering. A driver update didn't help. I used G.E.I.L. Black Dragon Memory. After installing Kingston memory, the problem was solved immediately.