# Screen Flickering on a Dell when Intel HD Graphics driver is installed

Tags: windows, drivers

When Intel HD Graphics driver is installed the screen starts to flicker.

Upon uninstalling the Intel HD Graphics driver and using a standard VGA driver, the flickering stopped. I have tried updating the graphics drivers many times but the issue still remains.

Comment: Have you checked your resolution settings? This could be one of the reasons. Another could be the 'screen refresh' setting.

Comment: More or less a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/371279/screen-flicker-with-intel-hd-graphics-driver